# Разъезжается основной блок в IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Не могу понять почему?! Во всех браузерах норм, в ие разъезжается основной блок в каталоге товаров [пример](http://мосматрас.рф/shop/256m2), помогите понять почему!?

Comment: Надо смотреть файл css, в котором описан класс для div'a left_sidebar

Comment: .left_sidebar { width:234px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }

с этим вроде как все норм...

самый прикол в том, что не во всех категориях разъезжается, хотя они шаблонные!

Comment: @Dimastik86, Из-за блока с тегами в подвале сайта.

Comment: прав, спасибо! не подскажешь как этого вылечить?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать тег <nobr>.

Comment: все, догадался! надо было поставить фикс ширину для подвала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, мой совет, - используйте CSS фреймворки, они очень простые, но и с кроссбраузерностью проблем не будет, могу посоветовать [Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-ru.com/), сам им пользуюсь и очень доволен!)

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, на восьмом осле уже спотыкается, поэтому не на все 100% он кроссбраузерный ;)

Comment: ну универсального инструмента пока нету(

Answer (score 7):

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') ){
  header("Location: http://www.google.com/intl/ru/chrome/browser/");
}
```

Вот так можно избавиться от назойливого IE :)

Comment: )) не вариант

Comment: ахах))) не знал как это сделать при помощи пхп, спасибо!)

Comment: Обращайтесь)